# Java runtime error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: StackMapTable format error: bad type array size

Tags: java, runtime-error

We are compiling and running in Java8.

Full error is:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: StackMapTable format error: bad type array size in method com.internal.connection.g.a(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Z)Lcom/internal/connection/model/ExecuteAnonymousResponse;

Java Version is:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Never seen this error and searching in the net, doesn't show much information. If this is of any useful, I had Java9 installed but after getting this error uninstalled it, just in case. But still same error.

I clean compiled dependencies in java 8 to be sure, but still no avail.

Comment: When is that exception showing?

Comment: That is first line of the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood when as what. Exception is shown when that class is loaded for the first time.

Comment: Is that your code, or is package `com.internal.connection` from some third-party library? Looks like obfuscated class library code (class `g`, method `a`) from a third-party library, so maybe the downloaded .jar file is corrupt and you should re-download it.

Comment: Right, it is our own internal code and it is run through proguard. We tried it with newer version of proguard, not running through proguard and still same error.